# How to check if a variable is a valid hex color in bash

Tags: bash, colors, hex

I need to have ha validity test to see if input from a user is valid. I need to know if the user writes a valid hex color.

Input could be "FFTTAA" which would not be valid as TT is not hex. It then need to abort so it is not written to the file. My problem is that i do not know how to single out hex as it is both letters and numbers. Which means a simple [0-9] would not work.

```
read -p "Use light, normal or bold (ex. light): " ANS1; read -p "Write size in mm (ex. 1.8): " ANS2; read -p "Write color in hexadecimal (ex. FFFFFF): " ANS3;

sed -i '/SwipeLauncherButtonStyle {/,/text/c\
    SwipeLauncherButtonStyle {\
    font: \$FONT_FAMILY '"$ANS1"' '"$ANS2"'mm;\
    text-color: \#'"$ANS3"';' file.css
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `[0-9]`, use either `[0-9A-F]` (to allow only uppercase) or `[0-9A-Fa-f]` (to allow lowercase as well). For example:

```
if ! [[ $ANSI3 =~ ^[0-9A-F]{6}$ ]] ; then
    # abort . . .
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

In CSS, [A valid colour must have either 3 or 6 hexadecimal digits](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#color-units). You can check this with a regular expression:

```
if [[ ${ANS3} =~ ^([[:xdigit:]]{3}){1,2}$ ]]; then 
    echo "Valid"; 
else
    echo "Invalid"; 
fi
```

Where `^` marks the beginning of the string, `$` marks the end and `{3}` means match three of the previous atom (`[[:xdigit:]]`) and `{1,2}` either one or two instances of the previous atom  (`(...)`), combining to make 3 or 6.

The [POSIX `[[:xdigit:]]`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#color-units) is equivalent to `[A-Fa-f0-9]` (taking care of both upper and lower cases).

Comment: Re: "A valid colour must have between 1 and 6 hexadecimal digits (`F` is the same as `00000F`)": That's not true. CSS requires either three hexadecimal digits or six (with `#ABC` being the same as `#AABBCC`). (I mean, it wouldn't surprise me to hear that browsers supported what you describe, but it's not "valid" in the usual sense of that term.)

Comment: @ruakh: Thanks. I sit corrected and have amended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Hex digits can be numbers or A-F.

You just need `[0-9A-Fa-f]`.